# timer in java: counter stuck at 1

Tags: java, timer, serversocket

Basically I make a timer turn for networking game, so if the timer hit 0 the turn will be given to another player. If the player making a move and the timer still not hit 0, the count will reset from 10. I don't know my mistakes at my timer.

```
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
    counter++;
    if(counter % second == 0){
      System.out.println("Times Up");
      TimeOut();
    }
    if(command.startsWith("BOX1")) {
      counter=0;
      counter++;
    }
    if(command.startsWith("BOX2")) {
      counter=0;
      counter++;
    }
    if(command.startsWith("BOX3")) {
      counter=0;
      counter++;
    }
    if(command.startsWith("BOX4")) {
      counter=0;
      counter++;
    }
    if(command.startsWith("BOX5")) {
      counter=0;
      counter++;
    }
    if(command.startsWith("BOX6")) {
      counter=0;
      counter++;
    }
    if(command.startsWith("BOX7")) {
      counter=0;
      counter++;
    }
    if(command.startsWith("BOX8")) {
      counter=0;
      counter++;
    }
    if(command.startsWith("BOX9")) {
      counter=0;
      counter++;
    }
    else{
      System.out.println("Time left:" + (second - (counter %second)) );
    }
  }
}, 3000, 3000);
```

So when my Server receive BOX1(Client make movement) the timer should be go 0 and increment again , but my counter stuck at 1

[image]

Comment: The image that you posted shows that it is stuck at `9` not `1`.

Comment: BTW, how many `BOX`s do you have?  Why can't your code be simplified to `if(command.startsWith("BOX")) `

Comment: @ScaryWombat i have 9 box , each box present a piece of image.
its stuck at 9 but in my program the value of the counter is stuck at 1.

 System.out.println("Time left:" + (second - (counter %second)) );

second=10

Comment: No wonder that the `counter` is stuck at 1, because `counter=0; counter++;` is equivalent to `counter = 1;` and you have these 2 lines in every branch.